# jQuery Validate File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a HTML file upload using jQuery Validate

I found I can use the meta option like:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   meta: "validate"
})

<input type="file" name="upload" class="{validate:{required:true,accept:'docx?|pdf'}}" />
```

But it does not appear to work. I need to add the `required` class anyways. Then the file type check will not work too of course. Do I need to do something additional?

Comment: You can leave the `required`. But can you do the client-side validation on before submit? You also need to do validation on the server-side though.

Comment: ...what I mean is: create a jQuery script for `.submit()` so you can validate before submitting.

Comment: @Alex R., Actually thats in the form submit handler... is that the wrong way of doing this?

Answer (score 67):

If you want to use jQuery's `validate` to check the **size** of the file, you can do so by doing the following :

1- load the additional methods file

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

2- add a custom method to validate the file size

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    // param = size (in bytes) 
    // element = element to validate (<input>)
    // value = value of the element (file name)
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param) 
});
```

3- use the newly added method as a validation rule to validate your input:

```
$('#formid').validate({
    rules: { inputimage: { required: true, extension: "png|jpe?g|gif", filesize: 1048576  }},
    messages: { inputimage: "File must be JPG, GIF or PNG, less than 1MB" }
});
```

**Note:** using the "accept" validation rule instead of "extension" result in MIME type error messages when you upload a file with a blank file type.

Comment: i get this error... e.validator.methods[o] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...,t;for(e=0;this.errorList[e];e++){var n=this.errorList[e];if(this.settings.highl...

Comment: Hmmm, if I make `required: false` it returns a `a.validator.methods[d] is undefined` error. It's not required to add a file to in my form.

Comment: You should include additional-method.js first, look like this
`<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>`

Comment: When I add your method, it works fine, except after I re-choose another image with size less than the threshold, the hint message doesn't disappear automatically. I have to re-click submit to have the hint message disappear again. How could I solve that problem? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the Note. That's helped me to change the message

Answer (score 11):

You can add a validation method to accomplish

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("uploadFile", function (val, element) {

          var size = element.files[0].size;
            console.log(size);

           if (size > 1048576)// checks the file more than 1 MB
           {
               console.log("returning false");
                return false;
           } else {
               console.log("returning true");
               return true;
           }

      }, "File type error");
```

And Use it like this -

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#quote_form').validate({
      rules: {
           image: {
              required: true,
              extension:'jpe?g,png',
              uploadFile:true,
              }
             }
          });
       });
```

I hope this will help you..

Comment: the uploadFile rule works, but the extension rule doesn't . Are you ok?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read and tried it this way: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#extension ?

I mean rather than adding the validate rules to the class have you tried to just instantly add them in validate init?

Comment: Good way to check MIME type. But we need to check the file extension